# How can I get active facebook account from device?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am using this code portion but it returns null.

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
accounts = AccountManager.get(Login.this).getAccountsByType("com.facebook");
String possibleEmail;

for (Account account : accounts) 
{
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) 
    {
        possibleEmail = account.name;
        Log.e("Email", possibleEmail);
    }
}
```

But it is working for("com.google").

Answer (score 0):

Its better to printout all the types and see whats need to be use to access, as extracting them by type name need to be exact match.

```
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+

    AccountManager acMng = AccountManager.get(this.getApplicationContext());
    if(acMng!=null) {           

    Account[] accounts = acMng.getAccounts();
    String possibleEmail;

    if(accounts!= null) {
    for (Account account : accounts) 
    {
         Log.e(( account.name , account.type );
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) 
        {
            possibleEmail = account.name;
            Log.e(("Email :",  possibleEmail);
        }
    }
    }
```

As in my testing device type for facebook is -- **com.facebook.auth.login**

So I think it need to be :

```
 accounts = AccountManager.get(Login.this).getAccountsByType("com.facebook.auth.login");
```

Comment: @Neha Madam Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481360/how-can-i-get-email-ids-of-yahoo-microsoft-account