# How Can I Get email ids of Yahoo/Microsoft Account

Tags: android, android-account

Is it possible to get Yahoo/Microsoft  email id/ ids which are configured with PlayStore app in android device. I use **com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.sync** for Yahoo. But Not Working .May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Here is my code:

```
public String[] allemails()
        {

             _accountMgr = AccountManager.get(getActivity());
               // Account [] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccounts();

              //  Account [] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
             Account [] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccountsByType("com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.sync");

             numberOfEmail = accounts.length ;
                String [] emailAddress = new String[numberOfEmail];

                r = 0;
                for (Account account : accounts) {
                    accountsList = account.name.toString();
                    emailAddress[r] = accountsList;
                    r += 1;

                }

                MyAlertDialog f = new MyAlertDialog();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putStringArray("Title", emailAddress);
                f.setArguments(args);

                return  emailAddress;
        }
```

Comment: **How** is it not working? Does it explode?

Comment: Not Working. I am stuck @SLaks

Comment: **How** is it not working? What happens? Does it explode? Do you get an error? Did you read what the error says?

Comment: When i use this..My Yahoo id not showing . If i use getAccounts() Then show all email Ids

Comment: I think getAccountsByType() Not working when i use it .@SLaks

Comment: how you know "com.yahoo.mobile.cllient.share.sync" is correct type ? and its have typo .. is should be "com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.sync"

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Mam , I replace this,But not working :o

Comment: Did u check the type .. as in my test device its - com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.account

Comment: Now Working Madam (y) .

Comment: Good :) can i add it as ans !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the account type

> com.yahoo.mobile.cllient.share.sync

to

> com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.account

Comment: Madam : please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590681/textview-button-not-showing-after-add-datepicker-in-android

Comment: Above link is not working, could you please share details for getting only Microsoft emails from AccountManager. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but it might help someone.To get google,yahoo,microsoft accounts...use either of the three:

```
String email = null;

    Pattern gmailPattern = Patterns.DOMAIN_NAME;
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (gmailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            email = account.name;
        }
    }
    Account[] accounts1 = manager.getAccountsByType("com.android.email");
    for (Account account : accounts1) {
        if (gmailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            email = account.name;
        }
    }
    Account[] accounts2 = manager.getAccountsByType("com.android.exchange");
    for (Account account : accounts2) {
        if (gmailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            email = account.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the exchange type include microsoft office 365 accounts as well?

Comment: haven't tried that one yet but let me try and i'll get back to you.Meanwhile also do the same.And if it helped you can mark it as an answer

Comment: I have discovered that for Microsoft Office 365 accounts and similar there are additional packages to be considered. These are `"com.microsoft.android.enterprise15", "com.microsoft.skydrive", "com.microsoft.workaccount"`

Comment: glad you found the solution.I don't have a microsoft 365 account.

Comment: also with the account.name and all emails you might need already registered in your phone,you can get all their types.Its how I ended up with the three